# Google Sheets query with special transpose

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm struggling to write a query that appears more complex than anticipated, here a sample of the data to process

| CW6 | CW7 | CW8 | CW9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | A |
| B | D | E | B |

Here the result expected at the end:

| Item | CW |
| --- | --- |
| A | "CW6 CW9" |
| B | "CW6 CW7 CW9" |
| C | "CW8" |
| D | "CW7" |
| E | "CW8" |

Any idea how to achieve this ?
What I've tried in many steps:

`=transpose(query(<data>,"Select *",1))` to transpose my data

Then I used

```
=transpose(
     query(
        transpose(<data transposed>),,9^9
     )
)
```

to join all columns

Then I select all the unique values I want to retrieve the column header (CWxx)

```
=query(
     unique(flatten(<Data>)),
     "Select Col1 where Col1 is not null"
)
```

Finally I join the data that were transposed to get it in one string (ie 1 column):

```
=JOIN(" ", QUERY(< data transposed and joined>,"SELECT Col2 WHERE Col1 contains '"&A1&"'",0))
```

At the end I got the wanted array but I have to copy the last join formula on each line what I do not want to do as my values are dynamic

Any idea how to achieve this (or a simpler way to avoid all these steps) ?

Comment: This seems like a task to do via google script, would you consider doing that? Here is a very simple example: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: I would like to avoid having scripts (and have this calculation when cells are changed); Formulas could do the job ?

Comment: Could you share a public copy of the sheet you used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(A2:D))), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(A2:D="",,A2:D&"×"&A1:D1&"×"&A1:D1)), "×")), 
 "select max(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)))})
```

[image]

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(A2:D))), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), """"&TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(A2:D="",,A2:D&"×"&A1:D1&"×"&A1:D1)), "×")), 
 "select max(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)))&""""})
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(TO_TEXT(SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(A2:D)))), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0), TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(TO_TEXT(
 IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(A2:D="",,A2:D&"×"&A1:D1&"×"&A1:D1)), "×"))), 
 "select max(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)))})
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this proposal. I spent really some time to understand it! I obtain a specific behaviour when the letters are changed to numbers (cell's type can remain as plain text). In your example, replace A=10, B=20, C=30 ... And in cell B2 set B to 200 instead of 20. 200 is seen CW8 ... Any idea ?

Comment: Terrible, it works well now. Many thanks, you saved my day!